# Prove that there are numbers $c$ and $d$ with $a \leq c \lt x_o \lt d \leq b$ such that $f(c)=f(d)=0$, but $f(x) \gt 0$ for all $x$ in $(c,d)$.

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

Exercise 4a from Chapter 8 of Spivak's *Calculus* asks the following:

> Suppose that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and that $f(a)=f(b)=0$. Suppose also that $f(x_0) \gt 0$ for some $x_0$ in $[a,b]$. Prove that there are numbers $c$ and $d$ with $a \leq c \lt x_o \lt d \leq b$ such that $f(c)=f(d)=0$, but $f(x) \gt 0$ for all $x$ in $(c,d)$.

The solution manual offers a picture - from the picture, it was not initially apparent to me that this proof generalizes to any $f$ satisfying the assumptions. Here is the general proof.

---

We will construct a function $g$, which mirrors $f$ symmetrically across the midpoint of the interval $[a,x_0]$. $g$ can be defined as follows: $g(x)=f(-x +(a+x_0))$. Note that this function is necessarily continuous because $f$ is continuous, as is the function $h(x)=-x+(a+x_0)$. Further, we see that $g(a)=f(x_0)$, $g(x_0)=f(a)$, and $g(a+x)=f(x_0-x)$, as desired.

Next, consider the set $S_g:=\left\{x \in [a,x_0]\  |\  \forall y \in [a,x]:g(y) \gt 0\right\}$. $a \in S_g$ because $g(a)=f(x_0) \gt 0$ and $x_0$ is an upper bound. Therefore, $S_g$ has a least upper bound $\alpha$. By continuity, $\alpha \not \in S_g $. If it were, we would have a neighborhood to the right of $\alpha$ where all members were also $\gt 0$. This would disqualify $\alpha$ as an upper bound, a contradiction. Thus, $\alpha \not \in S_g$, which implies that $g(\alpha) \leq 0$ and $\alpha \neq a$...so $\alpha \in (a,x_0]$.

Suppose $g(\alpha) \lt 0$. Again, by continuity, there is a left neighborhood of $\alpha$ where all members are $\lt 0$. This would disqualify $\alpha$ as the *least* upper bound, a contradiction. So $g(\alpha) = 0$. Moreover, it is clearly the first such instance and for any $x$ on the interval $[a,\alpha)$, $g(x) \gt 0$.

To deduce what $\alpha$ is from the perspective of $f$, recall that $g(x)=f(-x+a+x_0)$. Therefore, $g(\alpha)=f(-\alpha+a+x_0)=0$. Let $c = -\alpha+a+x_0$. Because $\alpha \in (a,x_0]$, $c \in [a,x_0)$. Similarly, if $g(x) \gt 0$ on the interval $[a,\alpha)$ then $f(x) \gt 0$ on the interval $(- \alpha+a+x_0,x_0]$, which is equivalent to $(c,x_0]$.

To determine the first instance of a $0$ on the interval $[x_0,b]$, no new function is required. Simply use the least upper bound $\alpha$ of the set $S_f:=\left\{x \in [x_0,b]\ | \ \forall y \in[x_0,x]:f(y) \gt 0 \right\}$. Using similar arguments, we have that $f(\alpha)=0$. Let $\alpha = d$. Note that $d$ can take on any value on $(x_0,b]$. Further, for any $x \in [x_0,d)$, we have $f(x) \gt 0$.

In conclusion, we have the interval $a \leq c \lt x_0 \lt d \leq b$ where for any $x \in (c,d): f(x)\gt 0$.

Comment: I see nothing used about the function $f$ that is not given in the theorem. So it doesn't need to "generalize" to such functions, since it already covers them. Where do you suspect it of using a property of $f$ that is not part of the hypothesis of the theorem?

Comment: The only thing I find odd about this is why it bothers to define the function $g$ instead of just setting $S = \{x \in [a,x_0]\mid f(x) \le 0\}$. The supremum of this set will be the same $\alpha$ found by the method in the proof.

Comment: @PaulSinclair assuming I understood your question correctly, my original take on the problem was that it was an existential claim. I thought that the goal was to prove: 

$\exists f \text{ such that } ...$. When the author then drew a picture as the 'solution', I interpreted this as further confirmation that the problem was about proving the existence of a function. As to your second comment, that appears correct. I was caught in the mindset of defining things as consecutive intervals. Thank you for the input!

Comment: So this is *your* proof, not Spivak's? The somewhat round-about reasoning is more understandable then. It was surprising that someone as experienced as Spivak would choose such a round-about argument - unless there was something else he was also trying to accomplish with it - but for someone with limited experience, it is actually a good effort. Spotting what is necessary and what isn't is something you learn over time.

Comment: Though as I look again, I don't see any proof that $f(c) = 0, f(d) = 0$. (You do have a proof that $g(\alpha) = 0$, but it doesn't get translated to $f(c)$, and there is nothing about $f(d)$.)

Comment: @PaulSinclair I see my mistake. Thank you. I'll resubmit with the corrections shortly.